# LabelFor doesn't work when I use DataAnnotations and DisplayName - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, displayname-attribute, html.labelfor

I have a folder called "ModelMetaData.cs" where I have a class called "InspeccioModelMetaData.cs" with these code:

```
[DisplayName("Id")]
public string IdInspeccio { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Data de caducitat")]
public DateTime DataCaducitat { get; set; }
```

And the Model have these code:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(InspeccioModelMetaData))]
public partial class Inspeccio
{
```

...

```
public System.DateTime DataCaducitat { get; set; }
```

...

In the view when I use @Html.DisplayNameFor it works but when I use

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataCaducitat, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

it doesn't.

I have searched the solution by googling but nothing works for me...

Can someone helps me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding your solution?

Comment: Yes, but It doesn't work.. thanks :)

Comment: Okey dokes. What is the value of the label when it is rendered, if it isn't `Data de caducitat`?

Comment: It's DataCaducitat. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that these metadata classes are in the same namespace as the model.